# UIButton Inside Nested ScrollViews is Highlighting but not Triggering Segue or IBAction When Tapped - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a UIButton that is within a nested scrollview (a vertically paged scrollview inside a horizontally paged scrollview). My problem is when I tap the button it highlights but it does not trigger a segue that I have it linked to. I then tried to link it to an IBAction function where I placed a breakpoint and when I tapped the button I did not hit that breakpoint, so my button is also not triggering IBActions either.

I've tried turning off delays content touches for both scrollviews and that didn't work. All that did was make the button highlight as soon as I tapped it rather than weighting a little bit before highlighting. Either way, my button highlights when I tap it but none of my outlets (segues or IBActions) are triggering which I thought was very strange. I've found other people online with similar issues but their buttons didn't even highlight. Mine highlights so I know its getting input from the user.

Here is how I am instantiating the nested scrollview. The main horizontal scrollview is created in my storyboard then in its ViewController viewDidLoad method I do this to nest the vertical scrollview. The vertical scrollview is what contains my button.

```
let readingVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ReadingViewController") as! ReadingRingViewController
readingVC.read = reading.minutesRead
readingVC.goal = reading.minutesGoal
readingVC.selectedDate = selectedDate
readingVC.today = today
let readingView = readingVC.view
let scrollPage2 = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(readingView.bounds.size.width,0,readingView.bounds.size.width, readingView.bounds.size.height))
scrollPage2.addSubview(readingView)
scrollPage2.contentSize = CGSize(width: readingView.bounds.size.width, height: readingView.bounds.size.height*2)
scrollPage2.pagingEnabled = true;
scrollPage2.alwaysBounceVertical = true
scrollPage2.userInteractionEnabled = true
let readingBottomView = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ReadingBottomViewController").view
let scrollPage2Bottom = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0,readingView.bounds.size.height,readingBottomView.bounds.size.width, readingBottomView.bounds.size.height*2))
scrollPage2Bottom.addSubview(readingBottomView)
        scrollPage2Bottom.contentSize = CGSize(width: readingBottomView.bounds.size.width, height: readingBottomView.bounds.size.height)
scrollPage2.addSubview(scrollPage2Bottom)
scrollPage2.sendSubviewToBack(scrollPage2Bottom)
```

Here is the code for the viewController that my button is in. I've linked it to the IBAction and also linked it to another viewController as a push segue

```
@IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {
    var x = 0
    var y = 0
    x = y + x
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "StartReading" {
        let destVC = segue.destinationViewController
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my own question. The reason the button's actions were not working was because I was adding the view the button was in as a subview but forgetting to also add the view controller for the button's view as a subviewcontroller. So I inserted the lines following lines of code after I instantiated readingVC and set its member variables:

```
self.addChildViewController(readingVC)
readingVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Now the button works exactly as expected

Comment: It work like a charm! thank u very much!!! In Objective-C: [self addChildViewController:viewController];
            [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
            [scrollView addSubview:viewController.view];